# How to make a dictionary with multiple keys, and a cheap Contains operation?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, key

Essentially what I want to do is a `Dictionary<List<TKey>, TValue>`. I want many values that point to the value (rough sketch: [image: paint skills overwhelming]) and yes this **can** be done with a `Dictionary<List<TKey>, TValue>`, but I also need to check whether a key exists (essentially - I am given values A to Z, I need to find if they are keys, and if so retrieve the value associated with them) and going through each list to find the value seems like a very expensive operation (I haven't tested yet but I just get the feeling the operation is ridiculously expensive). I've seen a `MultiValueDictionary` but not a multi-key dictionary. Any help? Thanks :)

Comment: You could implement that with an underlying `Ductionary<TKey, ValueHolder<TValue>>`, `ValueHolder<T>` being a private class used for indirection. And maybe you don't even need that but you could duplicate the value.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski That does all I need, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you go with a simple `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` that maps your keys potentially to the same value. If your concern is `TValue` being a value type that needs to be updated consistently for all its associated keys, then use a class wrapper around it, so that all the said keys would point to the same instance.

For example:

```
public class Wrapper<TValue>
{
    public TValue Value { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var d = new Dictionary<char, Wrapper<int>>();
    d.Add('A', new Wrapper<int> { Value = 1 });
    d.Add('B', d['A']);   // same value as 'A'
    d.Add('C', new Wrapper<int> { Value = 2 });
    d.Add('D', new Wrapper<int> { Value = 3 });
    d.Add('E', d['D']);   // same value as 'D'
    d.Add('F', d['D']);   // same value as 'D'

    d['B'].Value--;   // decrement 'B' value from '1' to '0'
    Console.WriteLine(d['A'].Value);   // new value shows up for 'A' too
}
```

Comment: That does exactly what I need. Thanks :) (will accept in 3)

Comment: Cheers! For convenience, you can find a wrapper implementation [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/30b5be81-8e47-43b2-92b9-111851c477a5/is-there-any-wrapper-class-for-integer-in-net-framework-library?forum=csharplanguage#f09675aa-a527-4e71-a99c-afc3b1b95308).